# Search for a 'diff value than' from another sheet and return a cell from this row

Tags: excel

Sheet 1:(the one to copy to)

```
Redial     |    DND |  New call
value1     |    value2  |  value3  -> values that I want
```

Sheet 2: (the one with the info to copy from)

```
Redial     |    DND |  New call
HJSG       |    7654    |  eur
```

What I want is to search if the value of "new call" is NOT eur, and if so, copy the value of sheet2(redial,DND and New call) to the sheet1.

Im trying to do arrays with Index and vlookup and if's but I cant really figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In `Cell A2` of `Sheet1` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$10,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10<>"eur",ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW(INDEX( Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10,1 ))+1 ),ROWS($1:1))),  "")
```

Drag/Copy down and across (to right) as required. This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]